# C# tostring(radix)

Tags: c#, javascript, radix

I have the following line in javascript:

```
c = Number(string_1.charCodeAt(i) ^ string_2.charCodeAt(u)).toString(16);
```

I need to rewrite it in c#, this is what I got so far:

```
string c = (Convert.ToChar(string_1[i]) ^ Convert.ToChar(string_2[u])).ToString(16);
```

I'm not able to enter radix value in ToString method. Any suggestions how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToString` to write out a value in a different base (Note that only certain bases are supported;  16 is one of them, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) for details) :

```
int i = 16;
var str = Convert.ToString(i, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to `.ToString("X");` which is the hexadecimal format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Or even easier, if you're looking for base 16 (aka hexadecimal):

```
int x = 12345 ;
string v = string.Format( "0x{0:X4}" , x ) ;
```

will give you

```
v = "0x3039"
```